# Push operation using spread operator is not working in Lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, api

I have a child lwc component which is getting array-data from a parent lwc component.

In my child component, I have the following code

```
 console.log('this.selectedItems kkkkkkkk    ' + JSON.stringify(this.selectedItems));
    console.log('this.globalSelectedItems uuuuuu    '+JSON.stringify(this.globalSelectedItems));
    this.globalSelectedItems.push(...this.selectedItems); 
    console.log('this.globalSelectedItems 8888888    '+JSON.stringify(this.globalSelectedItems));
    const arrItems = this.globalSelectedItems;
```

My problem is that the line -

```
  this.globalSelectedItems.push(...this.selectedItems);
```

is not working.

The lines

```
  console.log('this.selectedItems kkkkkkkk    ' + JSON.stringify(this.selectedItems));
    console.log('this.globalSelectedItems uuuuuu    '+JSON.stringify(this.globalSelectedItems));
```

are printing values in the console. However, the push operation is still not working and the line

```
  console.log('this.globalSelectedItems 8888888    '+JSON.stringify(this.globalSelectedItems));
```

is not getting printed on the console

The samples printed on the console are the following :

```
  this.selectedItems kkkkkkkk    
  [{"value":"0033O000015fyhyQAA","label":"Dan Test Brown"}]


  lwcMultiSelectLookup.js:1 this.globalSelectedItems uuuuuu    
  [{"value":"0033O000015mMXuQAM","label":"John Doe"}]
```

I am not sure what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you share a sample of the console output?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `globalSelectedItems` is defined as `@api globalSelectedItems;`. Is that correct? If so, you'll find that the object is immutable, so you have to notify the parent of any data changes.